# Is my multimeter broken?

Tags: transistors, led, current-measurement, multimeter

First, let me say that I'm very new to electronics so this issue may just be down to me doing something wrong.

Here is my multimeter:
[image]

It started when I was trying to test the gain of a PNP transistor. The expected values were 0.016mA for base and 3.1mA for collector. I kept getting 0.03mA for both. My multimeter has 1 terminal for A and another terminal for everything else, including mA (I was using the mA terminal). I assumed I was just doing something wrong but eventually decided to test the multimeter on a simple circuit.

I connected an LED, a 470 ohm resistor and the multimeter in series as a test. With no multimeter, the LED is on. Using the A terminal, the LED is on and has a value of 0.014A. Using the mA terminal, the LED is **not** on and the reading is 0.03mA.

So my question is: am I just messing this up somehow or is my multimeter broken?

The options I have considered are:

1. The multimeter is working and I have just made a mistake somewhere.
2. The current in the test circuit with the mA terminal is actually 0.03mA. The low current could be the reason the LED isn't turning on. But why would it work fine using the A terminal?
3. The multimeter with the mA terminal is not forming a circuit for some reason. This would explain why the LED won't switch on. However, the multimeter reading does increase from 0 to 0.03mA once the battery is connected, which suggests some current is flowing.

All in all, I'm very confused. I only started this a few days ago so have no idea what I'm doing. I did test the current of the same test circuit yesterday (using the mA terminal) and I didn't notice it giving a really low value, but I wasn't really paying attention.

Comment: Check the fuse. The `mA` terminal is fused, so if you measure a current higher than it is rated for, the fuse will burn.

Comment: You need to edit your question to include a make, model and photo of your meter. Pictures are much better than words. If you can include a second photo of one of your test measurements we may help further.

Comment: Does the LED light up if you switch to a higher mA range? Your multi-meter might have a high internal resistance for lowest mA range.

Comment: You can always use the meter to measure the drop across a resistor and calculate the current with Ohms Law as I=V/R.  Many times that is easier than putting the meter in line.

Comment: Just about everyone blows a DMM fuse at least once to learn to be more careful. . Time to open it and replace with a poly fuse ( order a bunch of various sized Polyfuses for future use, they cost less than courier, & get current shunt resistors for .05v drop max or 0.1v drop in 1/2W

Comment: Why don't you perform some simple control experiments? Take a AA battery, and a 150-Ohm resistor, nothing fancy, no LED nor transistor. And then just check if your readings are in line with Ohm's Law.

Comment: The make, model and photo of the meter is less relevant than a simple drawing on how you actually connect the wires. Maybe you don't know to connect current measurements in series, or something else.

Comment: @AliChen Thank You! I got the exact value for current that I expected using the A terminal but still 0.03mA for the mA terminal, so I guess the meter is broken. I suppose it must be the fuse – I assumed the current would be 0 if I had blown it.

Comment: When measuring current it is better to use a series shunt resistor and measure the voltage across the resistor.  Or buy lots of fuses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After testing the multimeter some more with help from the comments on my question I found out that the fuse was blown. Thank you everyone for your help.

Comment: A quick tip: you can use a diode/continuity test to check if your fuse tripped. It is THE most common problem with a faulty current reading. In a semester, my first year students uses roughly 30 to 40 fuses. Most often, they tried to measure a current in parallel.